# How to add submenu dynamically in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

In one of my program, I want to add a 'Recent Used' feature in the 'File' Menu. So, when users select 'File > Recent Used', it will show up a sub menu with the history list. I know how to append a sub menu using AppendSubMenu. But the problem is the 'File' menu is created statically when initializing the menubar as well as 'File','View' menus, etc. How to append a submenu dynamically at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [wxFileHistory](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_history.html) and avoid updating the menus manually completely.

But if you really need to do it, it's easy to do too, of course: use [wxMenuBar::GetMenu()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu_bar.html#a7935fbf932f070f13c31b213c5e3419d) to get the `wxMenu` pointer and then call [wxMenu::AppendSubMenu()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html#a6e5821042919502670e8fdab77a5f7a8).

Comment: Thanks. wxFileHistory is a great simplification. :)